# Does converting a disk from basic to dynamic require a reboot?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, database, sql

I'm finding conflicting info on converting a disk from basic to dynamic and have a few questions.

Will it require a reboot?

The server with the disk in question is hosting SQL Server 2008 R2, and the disk in question contains all the data, tlogs, and backups done nightly. I need to shrink a partition and expand another, so I'm curious if converting the database disk from basic to dynamic will affect accessibility to the database or any functionality? The database is for Blackboard, which is hosted on a separate application server and reads/writes from the database constantly.

Thank you for your expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, converting the disk from Basic to Dynamic does not require a reboot.

Comment: Is there any reason NOT to convert the disk to dynamic? It is not hosting the OS.